# SwiftUI Passing Data off of an NavigationLink list

Tags: swift, swiftui, view, swiftui-navigationlink, pass-data

I have a list of NavigationLinks which gets generated by an foreach loop and im trying to pass a value to another class (not view), that is not connected to the NavigationLink-view,  with a click on the link. Thats because the value that I want to change in the external class, determines what gets shown on the view that the NavigationLink leads to.

This is my first view with the links. The line that is commented out is what I actually want to do, but because its a view I can't do it that way. `location.locationNumber` is a value of the class and sets what is being shown at the other view.

```
struct ListOfPlacesView: View {
    
     @StateObject var location = Location()
    @StateObject var places = Places()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List{
                ForEach (places.allPlaces.dropFirst(), id: \.self) { index in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailInformationView()){
                        Text(index[0])
                    //    location.locationNumber = Int(index[4]) ?? 0
                    }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("All Places")
    }
}
```

Example: If I click on the 6. NavigationLink on the list, `int(index[4])` has the value 6 and I want to change `location.locationNumber` to that value.

```
class Places: ObservableObject{
    
    let allPlaces: [[String]] =
    
    [["no sight",
      "No information",
      "https://www.wikipedia.com",
      "No information",
      "No information"],
     
     ["Tower of London",
      "The Tower of London, officially Her Majesty's Royal Palace and Fortress of the Tower of London, is a historic castle on the north bank of the River Thames in central London. It lies within the London Borough of Tower Hamlets, which is separated from the eastern edge of the square mile of the City of London by the open space known as Tower Hill. It was founded towards the end of 1066 as part of the Norman Conquest. The White Tower, which gives the entire castle its name, was built by William the Conqueror in 1078 and was a resented symbol of oppression, inflicted upon London by the new ruling elite. The castle was also used as a prison from 1100 until 1952, although that was not its primary purpose. A grand palace early in its history, it served as a royal residence.",
      "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_Bridge",
      "1066",
      "1"],

     ["Tower Bridge",
      "Tower Bridge is a Grade I listed combined bascule and suspension bridge in London, built between 1886 and 1894, designed by Horace Jones and engineered by John Wolfe Barry with the help of Henry Marc Brunel. It crosses the River Thames close to the Tower of London and is one of five London bridges owned and maintained by the Bridge House Estates, a charitable trust founded in 1282. The bridge was constructed to give better access to the East End of London, which had expanded its commercial potential in the 19th century. The bridge was opened by Edward, Prince of Wales and Alexandra, Princess of Wales in 1894.",
      "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_Bridge",
      "1894",
     "2"],
```

etc...

This is my second view. The `places.getPlaces` function gets feeded the `location.locationNumber` and returns the wanted array of strings for the texts.

```
struct DetailInformationView: View {
    
    @StateObject var location = Location()
    @StateObject var places = Places()
    
    struct OwnColor {
        static let myOrange = Color("MyOrange")
    }

    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            
            Text("Whats In Sight")
                .font(.system(size: 30))
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .frame(width: 420, height: 20, alignment: .center)
                .padding()
                .background(OwnColor.myOrange)
            
            Text(places.getPlaces(PlaceNumber: location.locationNumber)[0])
                .frame(width: 350, height: 80, alignment: .leading)
                .font(.system(size: 30))
                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
            
            Text(places.getPlaces(PlaceNumber: location.locationNumber)[1])
                .frame(width: 350, height: 300, alignment: .center)
                .padding()
                .font(.system(size: 15))
                .lineSpacing(5)
            
            Text("Exists since : \(places.getPlaces(PlaceNumber: location.locationNumber)[3])")
                .frame(width: 350, height: 10, alignment: .center)
                .padding()
                .font(.system(size: 18))
            
                Link(destination: (URL(string: places.getPlaces(PlaceNumber: location.locationNumber)[2]))!){
                    Text("More On Wikipedia")
            }
                .frame(width: 300, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                .font(.system(size: 20))
                .background(OwnColor.myOrange)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .padding()
    }
    }
}
```

This is the external class with the value that needs to be changed. This is just the top of the class. It just gets the user position below, nothing that should have impact on the matter.

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation
import SwiftUI

class Location: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate, ObservableObject{
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    @Published var locationNumber = 0
```

Everything I've tried doesn't seem to work because I don't want to pass the value to a childView but to another independent class. Do you have any Idea how I could do this? And if you do, please try to explain on a beginner level. Sorry if this is badly explained, ask if you can't figure out something. Thank you!

Comment: As `location` and `places` seem to hold your data, pull them up to a View that is parent for both views in question and pass them down in the environment. That will asure that both views have the same copy of the data.

Comment: note: you should not have `@StateObject var location = Location()` and 
    `@StateObject var places = Places()` in your `DetailInformationView`, you already have them in your `ListOfPlacesView`. Look-up  `@StateObject` and `@ObservedObject/@EnvironmentObject`, how to use them and pass them around.

Comment: Okay I will do, thank you.